# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects (python urllib)

Tags: python, urllib

Writing a python program, and I came up with this error while using the `urllib.urlopen` function.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ChurchScraper.py", line 58, in <module>
html = GetAllChurchPages()
File "ChurchScraper.py", line 48, in GetAllChurchPages
CPs = CPs + urllib.urlopen(url)
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects


 url = 'http://website.com/index.php?cID=' + str(cID)
        CPs = CPs + urllib.urlopen(url)
```

Comment: You've snipped out the code and traceback in way that's really hard to read.   Please show the code with proper indentation separate from the traceback.

Comment: @Codygman: Thanks -- while nice -- aren't the way StackOverflow works.  Please go to the answer you accepted.  Please click the checkmark to indicate that you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

urlopen(url) returns a file-like object. To obtain the string contents, try

```
CPs = CPs + urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: Thanks ~unutbu! Code worked perfectly.. i had the same code about 20 lines up in the program :S

It's a bit late though (6:22) and it was easy to overlook. Thanks so much for the fast answer though!

Answer (score 2):

urllib.urllopen doesn't return a string, it returns an object
[doc](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen)

```
If all went well, a file-like object is returned.
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer Arkaitz! I can't believe I made that silly error.. one of those things you keep looking at and wonder what happened!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this line: `CPs = CPs + urllib.urlopen(url)` I assume `CPs` is a string however `urllib.urlopen(url)` returns a file like object.

If you want to join the contents of the file at `url` with `CPs` then you need to do something like this: `CPs = CPs + urllib.urlopen(url).read()`.

Answer (score 0):

What is CPs? It looks like it is a string. urlopen will return an instance of a file-like object, not a string. See - http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html.

The error is not thrown from the urlopen, but because you are trying to concatenate a string with an object instance.