# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance'

Tags: python, tkinter, concatenation

I have a program using GUI elements and returns the error

```
cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects
```

The Code is:

```
def PeopleSearch():
    query = SearchTerm
    query = ('what is '+ query)
    string = ("<center><font size = 14> " + query + ' </font></center><br><img src =picture')
    j = 0
    try:
        gs = GoogleSearch(query)
        gs.results_per_page = 100
        results = gs.get_results()
```

The indentations have been changed. Hmm. SearchTerm is basically from a textbox.

Comment: Try : `('what is '+ str(query))`

Comment: You can otherwise do an ugly hack and place `print dir(query)` just beneath `query = SearchTerm` that wioll give you all the attributes of the  query instance. Then you might see which attribute you should use.

Comment: When you say "SearchTerm is basically from a textbox", what does that mean? It's obviously not just the text from a text widget or you wouldn't have this problem. And tkinter doesn't have a "textbox" widget; it has a text widget and an entry widget, and text objects on a canvas.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me reproduce with a simpler example:

```
v = 42
query = ('what is ' + v)
```

You would get:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

But now, if you simply call `str`:

```
query = ('what is ' + str(v))
```

That will work. So you only have to make sure `str(query)` returns what you expect. Be careful, I don't know what kind of object you are manipulating, but you should check if there is any method to get the string representation of it.

**Related:**

- [TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects (python urllib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660954/typeerror-cannot-concatenate-str-and-instance-objects-python-urllib?rq=1)
- [Python: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844072/python-typeerror-cannot-concatenate-str-and-int-objects?rq=1)
- [Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206601/cannot-concatenate-str-and-list-objects?rq=1)
- [TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001664/typeerror-cannot-concatenate-str-and-int-objects?rq=1)
  [TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'type' objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179630/typeerror-cannot-concatenate-str-and-type-objects?rq=1)

Comment: please I  have same problem but when I use str function I get this error: `"need more than 1 value to unpack"
`

Comment: @Somar I can't help without code. Ask the question on stackoverflow and send me the link and I'll answer it.